# In scala, how to pass a default value to List.find?

Tags: list, scala

I would like to find an element in a list that matches a predicate and to get a **default value** if no elements matches the predicate. I want to do this idiomatically, without defining additional variables (one liner). 
Is there something similar to `getOrElse` of `HashMap`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is yet another example of why `Option` is great!

The `find` method returns an `Option`, and `Option` has a method `getOrElse` that does exactly what you want.

```
scala> List(1,2,3).find(_ > 4).getOrElse(0)
res0: Int = 0
```

When nothing is found, `find` returns `None`, which means the "else" value will be returned.